# Proving continuity in a multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How would I go about determining whether
$g(x,y)=\left( \displaystyle{\frac{x^2-y^2}{xy-y^2}}\right)$ where $x \neq y$ and $4-x$ where $x=y$,
is continuous at point $(2,2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't sshown us what you have tried so far so I'll just get you started. Note that if $x \ne y$ then $f(x,y)=\frac{x+y}{y}$. Also note that $f(2,2)=2$ and the general inequality $$\text{ if } \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}<\delta \text{ then }  \vert x-x_0\vert<\delta \text { and }\vert y-y_0 \vert < \delta.$$ Depending on whether $x \ne y$ or whether $x=y$ then $$f(x,y)-2=\frac{(x-2)-(y-2)}{y}$$ or $$f(x,y)-2=2-x$$. You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I have been looking over this am a little lost on whether i should be approaching the point from different directions or possibly equating?